# how to keep code folding on save in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

Each time I open a java file in my Android Studio editor I fold things that I don't want to see, (like comments and some functions) but then after closing and opening the project everything is unfolded again! how to make Android Studio to remember my folded areas on the code and save them alongside the files?